# unity3d PlayersPrefeb, can we save differents player info through player prefab?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making FPS,standalone game
i want to save different players information like name, last played level, remaining health, for every different player, so can we do this thing through players prefeb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **Save** player Info, Convert it to Json with `JsonUtility.ToJson` then Save it with `PlayerPrefs.SetString`.

To **Load** the Player Info, Load it with `PlayerPrefs.GetStrin`g the Convert the Json string to class with `JsonUtility.FromJson`.

Full Example:

```
class Playerinfo
{
    public string name;
    public string lastLevelPlayed;
    public float remainingHealth;
}
```

**Save**:

```
    Playerinfo playerInstance = new Playerinfo();
    playerInstance.name = "Farhan Ali";
    playerInstance.lastLevelPlayed = "5";
    playerInstance.remainingHealth = 50;

    //convert to Json
    string SerializedPlayer = JsonUtility.ToJson(playerInstance);

    //Save Player Info
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("pInfo", SerializedPlayer);
```

**Load**:

```
   //Load Player Info
    string loadInfo = PlayerPrefs.GetString("pInfo");

    Playerinfo loadedInstance = JsonUtility.FromJson<Playerinfo>(loadInfo);
    Debug.Log("Player name is " + loadedInstance.name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. and special thanks for using my name in example for attracting... :-p

Comment: one thing more can I get these fields like name and level index, by scene.like in Gui I write player name then how can I retrieve it into script, because I am bit new to unity3d @Programmer

Comment: You are welcome. I don't understand your second question. If you can create a new question with example of what you are talking about, that would be nice.

Comment: If you post the question again and provide code and be more specific on your problem,you will get my answer. The question was deleted before I got the chance to post the answer. If you don't want negative feedback from people, post your code and describe your problem next time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Best is to create a class for Player  and use the serialization process from .NET:

```
 [Serializable]
 public class Player 
 {
     public string Name { get; private set; }
     public int Points { get;  set; }
     public Player(string name, int points) {
         this.Name = name;
         this.Points = points;
    }
    public static void SaveData(Player item, string id)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, item as Player);
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(id, Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer()));
    }

    public static Player GetPlayer(string id) 
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(id) == false) { return null; }
        string str = PlayerPrefs.GetString(id);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(str));
        return bf.Deserialize(ms) as Player;
    }
}
```

id represents the current player. This should come from the player login I would guess. You still need to have a way to know who is playing from some input.

I got a longer explanation on how to make this more flexible [here](https://unitygem.wordpress.com/leaderboard-and-saving-data/).